# Angular - 'name' attribute for tag 'mat-select'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a form in Angular (see below). The `userEntitiesRoles` array can change, due to the logic of the page I'm creating. So I need to be sure that I provide a unique `name` attribute for the tag `mat-select`, otherwise I get problems. This is the reason why I tried to use a random string, with the Typescript code that is reported below. However, in this way, in the console of Chrome I get the error that you find at the end of the post, and I don't understand why. Do you have any suggestion?

**html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userEntitiesRoles">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>{{'USERS.ROLE' | translate}}</mat-label>
          <mat-select name="role-{{generateRandomString(5)}}" [(ngModel)]="item.role" required>
            <mat-option [value]="optionRole" *ngFor="let optionRole of roleOptions">{{optionRole | uppercase}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
generateRandomString(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }
```

**error:**

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'zAx5R'. Current value: 'rPFo6'..
```

Comment: Where is `generateRandomString` called?

Comment: @Shanie it is called just in the `name` attribute of the tag `mat-select`, as you can see in the html within the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big enough area. Probably a few hours of research to fully understand.
Basically Angular checks the DOM twice on initialization, first to set the values and the second time to make sure it was correct the first time.

On both occasions `generateRandomString(5)` will be called and will give a different answer each time.
Angular is afraid that this means you have a problem in your code so you get that error.

It won't happen in production mode but you should probably try to fix it anyway.

One approach:

It's usually better to not use functions in your html because they will be called every time something happens in the DOM (Mouse moves, click, scrolls).
It would be better to have a variable or array of variables that you set in ngOnInit or whenever they need to change.
Then change your html to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userEntitiesRoles; index as i">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>{{'USERS.ROLE' | translate}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select name="role-{{myRandomArray[i]}}" [(ngModel)]="item.role" required>
        <mat-option [value]="optionRole" *ngFor="let optionRole of roleOptions">{{optionRole | uppercase}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Another approach:

Use ChangeDetectorRef and call it in AfterViewInit

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

The second check happens before ngAfterViewInit and cd.detectChanges() tells Angular to go and recheck again.
This works when you have a variable that changes between checks it may not work on a function.

Probably you need to combine both approaches.

I'm not a doctor so some of this might be a bit off.
Here's an article about it [AngularInDepth](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned by you occurs when changes are triggered after the angular change detection has completed its check.
The life cycle hooks have completed the execution and then a new change is encountered.
To resolve the issue, you can manually trigger change detection by injecting ChangeDetectorRef (say you name it cdr) in the constructor and then using this.cdr.detectChanges().
This function triggers helps in triggering change detection cycle again manually.